# How can I access other elements of a Collection when doing render: collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

I am rendering a collection of objects, and, within the partial for each object that I render, I want to be able to output some info that requires a reference to an item in the collection I have yet to iterate over:

users_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @users = %w(Nelson Lisa Milhouse Janey)
end
```

index.html.haml:

```
= render :partial => "user", :collection => @users
```

_user.html.haml:

```
- if next_user
  %p= "#{next_user} likes #{user}!"
- else
  %strong NOBODY LIKES MILHOUSE
```

Is there an inherent accessor I don't know about, which I would substitute for "next_user", and call within the partial to get data on any of the other objects in the collection?

Or would I be doomed to passing "next_user" in as a local variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
= render :partial => "user", :collection => @users, :locals => { :users => @users}
```

You will then have access to `@users`.